# Как с помощью PHP добавлять данные на страницу?

Tags: php

Я только начал заниматься web'ом. Поэтому, если вопрос покажется вам крайне глупым, не судите строго.

У меня есть страница, на которой находятся столбцы таблицы(о ней позже) и поля, куда пользователь вводит данные. Потом эти данные проходят валидацию в js. Из js данные поступают в php post-запросом. Далее я эти данные преобразую по формуле. Последний шаг- вывести на страницу таблицу с преобразованными данными.

Проблема в последнем: я вывожу данные таким образом(т.е. добавляю теги к уже существующей таблице):

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $Xval . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $Yval . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $Rval . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $CONVERTED_INSIDE  . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $current_time  . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $executionTime . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

И они выводятся:

```
<tr><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>Попал</td><td>28 Aug 2022 22:14:26</td><td>0.000133</td></tr>
```

Но исключительно в консоль =(

Нигде ответа не нашел. Может существует другая команда для вывода текста в php. Или мне стоит изменить сам принцип вывода информации? И если да, то как?

Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Из js данные поступают в php post-запросом. Далее я эти данные преобразую по формуле.
> Последний шаг- вывести на страницу таблицу с преобразованными данными.

и конечно же, раз из браузера на сервер запрос идет через js, пытаетесь вывести им же, верно?

> И они выводятся:
> `<tr><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>Попал</td><td>28 Aug 2022`
> `22:14:26</td><td>0.000133</td></tr>`
> **Но исключительно в консоль =(**

конечно верно. замените в js `log.console()` на какой нибудь innerHTML\outerHTML например. и обязательно ознакомьтесь с методами "createElement" и "appendChild"

на вскидку вот вам простенький объект:

```js
var x ={
i: 0,
GI: function(id) {return document.getElementById(id)},
CE: function(tagN) {return document.createElement(tagN)},
AC: function (elem, newElem) {return elem.appendChild(newElem);},
UpdTable: function()
    {
    var cont = this.GI('my_table'); // id таблицы
    var nStr = this.CE('tr');
    this.AC(my_table, nStr);
    nStr.outerHTML =
    "<td>" + this.i++ + "</td><td>" + this.i++ + "</td><td>" + this.i++ + "</td>";
}}


// пример вызова
x.UpdTable();
```

```html
<input type='button' value='ok' onClick='x.UpdTable();'/>

<table id='my_table'>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: нет =( вывожу я через пхп

Comment: @Дмитрий, `нет =(` а в консоль оно типо само попадает, окееей, прям мистика какая-то =)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вам нужно развернуть локальный сервер, (openserver, denwer) создать php скрипт и запустить это в браузере.

Comment: на локалке я запускаю html файл с основной страницей

Comment: @Дмитрий, .html или .php?

Comment: .html Потому что так сказано в "тз"